# Send Email Without authentication in java using gmail smtp server and javamail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am using Javamail api and gmail smtp server to send mail in java without giving password. I have using  the below code. here i am using javax.mail jar file

```
     Properties props= new Properties();

     props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
     props.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
     props.put("mail.transport.protocal", "smtps");
     //Put below to false, if no https is needed
     props.put("mail.smtp.STARTTLS.enable", "false");
     props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");

     Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
```

I am getting the below error

```
      Must issue a STARTTLS command first. b4sm3005855pdh.2 - gsmtp
```

Is there any wrong in implementing the code? is it posssible to implement without password ? pls any one help me on this

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You've also misspelt "protocol".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the name of the property is "mail.smtp.starttls.enable".

Second, no, you can't send mail through Gmail without authenticating first, e.g., using your password.

Answer (score 0):

I Think it is not possible . if it will happen , any body can misuse of any other's mail address.