# Relay Data Securely From Desktop Application

Tags: java, email, ftp, desktop

How do I securely transmit data like feedback from a client's machine? When I use an [e-mail address with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-to-send-an-email-by-java-application-using-gmail-yahoo-hotmail) they can compromise my account however [non-authenticated sending is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300755/send-email-without-authentication-in-java-using-gmail-smtp-server-and-javamail) due to possible spam abuse and impersonation. Also [SMTP could be blocked](https://www.authsmtp.com/faqs/faq-4.html) so it's not 100% reliable.

Another way would be to [upload data onto my webserver using FTP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) but again, they will be able to compromise my FTP credentials.

I'm out of ideas, how is this supposed to be implemented in an easy way with proper security measures against exposing your credentials or not using any? I like the e-mail idea but it doesn't seem directly feasible.

Comment: Why would they use **your** credentials? Why not create credentials unique to the client?

Comment: @BrettWalker:
I only have 1 FTP account because it's a free hosting service...
Garry: How does this solve the problem? I still have to include credentials

Comment: You cannot create your own FTP Server? If you want to receive data from many clients securely then you need to have more control of the receiving point.

Comment: @BrettWalker:
Well, I don't know. I'm using `Cuccfree` if that matters. Can something good be done with this in term of sending and receiving the data?